# Uniqueness up to isometric isomorphism of predual of $(\sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda} H_\lambda)_{l_\infty}$ where $H_\lambda$ are Hilbert spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, preduals

This fact is an easy consequence of results of the paper [Classes of Banach spaces with unique isometric preduals.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-90/issue-2/Classes-of-Banach-spaces-with-unique-isometric-preduals/pjm/1102778987.full) by Leon Brown and Takashi Ito, but it looks like an overkill. Does anyone know a simpler proof?

Comment: For this particular space you can play the same game as in Example 2.1 here: http://math.uchicago.edu/~amwright/DavidsonWright2.pdf

Comment: @TomekKania I think you can post this as answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case, you can proceed similarly as in Example 2.1 [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20100610042345/http://math.uchicago.edu/%7Eamwright/DavidsonWright2.pdf). For more general results please consult a fantastic survey on unique preduals by G. Godefroy:

> G. Godefroy. Existence and uniqueness of isometric preduals: a survey. In: BorLuh Lin, editor, Banach Space Theory. Proc. of the Iowa Workshop on Banach Space Theory 1987, 131–193. *Contemp. Math*. **85**, 1989.

Comment: do you have electronic copy of this survey. Neither I, nor my institute don't have access to Contemporary Mathematics.

Comment: Norbert, the whole paper is fully available (at least to me) through google books: http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dmw0HHs9ppMC&lpg=PA131&ots=VVMFeKSQUx&dq=Existence%20and%20uniqueness%20of%20isometric%20preduals%3A%20a%20survey.&hl=pl&pg=PA131#v=onepage&q=Godefroy&f=false

Comment: unfortunately it is not fully avaliable for me even via your link